# Oracle trigger considered a new row as insert and update data

Tags: oracle

We have table 'Employee' and their corresponding 'Employee_Audit' table

When we try to add a new row, 'Employee_Audit' table containg the both 'insert' and 'update' entry

My Trigger is :

```
create or replace
TRIGGER Employee_AUDIT_TRIGGER
BEFORE DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON Employee FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF INSERTING THEN

INSERT INTO Employee _AUDIT (OPERATION, ID, VERSION, NAME, TYPE) 
VALUES('INSERT',:NEW.ID,:NEW.VERSION,:NEW.NAME,:NEW.TYPE);

ELSIF DELETING THEN

INSERT INTO Employee _AUDIT (OPERATION, ID, VERSION, NAME, TYPE)
VALUES ('DELETE',:OLD.ID,:OLD.VERSION,:OLD.NAME,:OLD.TYPE);

ELSIF UPDATING THEN

INSERT INTO Employee _AUDIT (OPERATION, ID, VERSION, NAME, TYPE) 
VALUES('UPDATE',:NEW.ID,:NEW.VERSION,:NEW.NAME,:NEW.TYPE);
END IF;
END Employee_AUDIT_TRIGGER;
```

Any one know the reason and no  exception is occur.

Comment: How are you adding the new row?  Are you sure that whatever program you are using is actually doing an `UPDATE` rather than a `DELETE` and an `INSERT`?  Are you sure there are no other triggers (or other bits of code) populating the `employee_audit` table?

Comment: Suppose we have Form's type page that containing the number of field We are adding the fresh new data on database on click the submit button (DAO layer using the hibernate functionality). 'Employee Audit ' table contain the data that showing the both insert and update operation on the same data. Only one trigger execute.

Comment: Then it sounds like Hibernate is generating a `DELETE` and an `INSERT`.  It sounds like you have a Hibernate question.  Unless, of course, you have some specific reason to believe that Hibernate is actually generating an `UPDATE`.